# Swap strongly signed assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, assemblies

I've a project which references to a 3th party library. The manufacturer of the library releases new versions on a regular basis. My ultimate goal is to be able to choose at runtime which version must be used during execution.

For now, I'm trying to load an assembly at runtime that has a higher version number than the one that was used during compilation. I compile my project, replace the 3th party library with a newer version and try to run the application. This is were I come into problems. I get an error saying:

"The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

I was not supprised to see this error, since the assembly is strongly signed. I looked for ways to bypass this, but without any luck so far.

I thought that Binding Redirection could help me, but it has the disadvantage that you can't specify a range of "newversions". Any combination should work, older with newer version and vice versa.

```
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.7.0" newVersion="1.2.8.0" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx

I've also looked at dynamic invocation, but then I loose type safety (my code extensively uses the types defined in the 3th party assembly). --> removing reference is difficult.

Removing the public key in the reference of the project definition didn't helped either. Any other assembly version then the one used during compilation fails.

```
<Reference Include="<assemblyname>">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Dependencies\<manufacturer>\1.2.7.0\<assemblyname>.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Note:
The logic to load and unload assemblies at runtime already exists.
There's no interface available for the 3th party library

Comment: Brr, this is asking for DLL Hell as a feature.  It doesn't have anything to do with strong naming, the exception is raised because of a mismatch in the [AssemblyVersion].  bindingRedirect is indeed the only good solution.  You're stuck unless you can convince the vendor to only increment the [AssemblyFileVersion] for compatible assemblies.  Incrementing [AssemblyVersion] otherwise is meant to mean "not compatible, don't even try".

Comment: @HansPassant AssemblyVersion, is indeed incremented, causing the manifest mismatch. Is it correct to say that manifest mismatch can only occur for strongly signed assemblies? Or does the problem also applies for non-signed assemblies?
[Assembly Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx)

Comment: No, only [AssemblyVersion] matters here.  It will fail on unsigned assemblies in the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'fix' this issue (work around is probably a better description) by handling the [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event on the AppDomain. Handling this event gives your code a chance to provide the assembly that needs to be loaded when all the normal methods of finding an assembly have failed to locate a matching version.

Inside the event handler you will need to check the ResolveEventArgs.Name property to see if the assembly is the one you need to load. The Name property will be the long name of the assembly being loaded - i.e. 'Widget.Net, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx'.

Once the correct load request has been identified, simply load the correct version of the assembly ([Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx), Assembly.Load, Assembly.LoadWithPartialName) and return it from the event handler. Note that Assembly.LoadWithPartialName is marked as obsolete, but seems to be the only way to handle this issue if the target assembly is in the GAC.

```
// application initialization
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("Widget.Net, Version="))
    {
        Assembly result = Assembly.LoadFrom("Widget.Net.dll");
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's important to be aware that while this 'solves' the problem, it's not a good solution in any sense. It completely subverts the normal version and strong name checking of assemblies used by the .Net framework. It's something that you do when you have no other option because (as in the question) a vendor has messed up versioning their assembly. You are also relying on their being no breaking changes to the classes defined in the assembly between the referenced version and the loaded version - i.e. that all the classes, properties, methods etc that you use still exist and have the same signatures.

To maintain at least a pretence of security, it would be a very good idea to at least check in the AssemblyResolve event handler that:

1. The assembly version loaded is newer than the version requested
2. The public key tokens of the loaded and requested assemblies match